# Chart macro resizing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates and formats a chart from user highlighted data to my required specifications, but realized that I had only been testing it with data where the first column was dates for the x axis. When this is not the case and all highlighted columns contain data for the chart, the macro fails.

```
Sub fullPageLine()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As chart
Dim i As Long, color As Long
Dim srs As Series

Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).chart

'Adjust chart size full vs half using number between ScaleHeight/Width and msoFalse
    cht.Parent.ShapeRange(1).ScaleWidth 1.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    cht.Parent.ShapeRange(1).ScaleHeight 1.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

'Format axes
With cht.ChartArea
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 0, 0)
End With

'Insert and format axis titles & plot area
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    With cht.PlotArea
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 422
        .Height = 220
    End With
    With cht.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle
        .Left = 5
        .Top = 20
        .Orientation = xlHorizontal
    End With

'Format title change left and top values to shift title location
With cht.ChartTitle
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 2
    With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .Size = 10
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Caps = msoAllCaps
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 0, 0)
    End With
End With

'Format legend
If cht.HasLegend Then
    With cht.Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
        .NameFarEast = "Arial"
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 7
    End With
End If


'Change chart series fill color

For i = 1 To cht.FullSeriesCollection.count
    ' Get the color based on series index
    Select Case i
        Case 1
            color = RGB(242, 105, 36)
        Case 2
            color = RGB(1, 0, 0)
        Case 3
            color = RGB(85, 85, 85)
        Case 4
            color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        Case 5
            color = RGB(192, 192, 192)

    End Select
    ' Assign series color formats
    '## NOTE: This only works for the cases defined in the above Select statement.
    Set srs = cht.FullSeriesCollection(i)
    With srs.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = color
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = bright
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

I get a pop up saying "System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259). Unspecified error", and have traced it back to this section of code:

```
With cht.PlotArea
   .Left = 10
   .Width = 422
   .Height = 220
End With
```

I do not understand why resizing the plot area would cause an error depending on the type of x axis the chart has. I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Error message starting with &H8 are usually permission type errors.  Either a pointer is addressing an area of memory that you don't have permission to access, or a file permission error.  Sometimes it is linked to pushing/puling variables onto the stack when subroutines are called. This type error may occur if the parameters arren't the same in the calling routine and a subroutine.

I would open the task manager as you run the program and see how many processes are being spawned when the program is running.  You may be creating a lot of processes and having some sort of stack issue.

Comment: It was a stack issue, Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you to accept the answer so other people can get the information faster so it helps the community @ahb23